# OpenERP 7 HR Payslip Python Code

Tags: odoo

I am trying to create a salary Rule called Basic Daily with the following python code:

```
result = contract.wage * worked_days.WORK100.number_of_days
```

But it gives the error: wrong python code defined for salary rule.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]It seems you have not define working schedule in your contract. If you want to use work days then you have to define working schedule in your contract, form where it calculate numer of days of working and number of days leaves

Comment: Ok so I figured out the issue was that to use "Work100" I had to have a "Work100" specified in the "code" column when creating the payslip. I guess you are probably referring to the same. I am unable to open the attached image.